# Typescript syntax dosn't seem to get compiled

Tags: node.js, typescript

The `!` character doesn't seem to be recognized when trying to compile the file.

[image]

If I do not use it, I get these errors(for context, not really important, I believe):

[image]

Point is, if I want to avoid those errors, I have to either use the non null assertion operator `!` or to test whether or not these objects are null before using them.

Code runs like a charm using tests to verify the objects are not null, but for some reason, when trying to use the `!`, I get that Unexpected token error. Any clue how that could be fixed?

I have added

```
module.exports = {
  module:{
    rules:[
      {test: /\.ts$/, use: 'ts-loader'}
    ]
  }
};
```

to my wepback.config.js
and now, I'm getting an `Error:cannot find module 'typescript', Require stack:` error.

[image]

Comment: It kind of sounds like your current Webpack configuration is parsing the `.ts` as Javascript, not Typescript, or something like that..? Does other Typescript syntax throw errors too?

Comment: Can you post code instead of images?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I'm not sure, I'm learning typescript right now and I don't know it's particular syntax. If you could give me an example, I could test to see if I get errors. Also, double quotes throws same error.

Comment: Just use *any* Typescript syntax other than non-null assertion to see if it throws an error too, take your pick and see if it compiles

Comment: @CertainPerformance I tried doing a `var message:string=""` and it throws an unexpected token error at the `:`. It's basically the same error.

Comment: @VLAZ I'm not sure code is the central concern of this question.

Comment: Yep, sounds like the Typescript isn't being complied as Typescript. You may need something like `test: /\.ts$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',` in your config, don't know what sort of setup you have

Comment: @NAlexP I can't read the first image due to the low contrast, so I don't even know what syntax you've used. If code is not important, then remove the images and see if the question is still answerable.

Comment: @CertainPerformance the examples of that I found on the internet had a `test` prop on an anonymous object declared in a `rules` list in some `model` object. Can I simply write `test: /\.ts$/, use: 'ts-loader'` in the webpack config?

Comment: Maybe. I'm not entirely sure what your setup is, or the intended target, but Webpack *can* use ts-loader to parse TS files. There are other ways to do it too, but I think ts-loader is the best way when integrating with Webpack. Of course, to use ts-loader, you also have to install Typescript

Comment: just `npm install typescript` will fix it.

Comment: `npm install typescript --save-dev` did it. Any clue why my globally installed ts module didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

`npm install typescript --save-dev` fixed the problem.
I'm still courious why my globally installed typescript module(`npm -i -g typescript`) didn't work, though.